# How do you add re-usable sub-models to a larger model

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to model a simple quadruped robot, and the legs contain four segments. Since the legs are identical, instead of duplicating the leg SDF inside the main model SDF file, is there some way I can model the leg once in a separate SDF file and "include" it four times in the SDF file for the "complete" robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8413/how-do-you-add-re-usable-sub-models-to-a-larger-model/) by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-04-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `<include>` tag can be used as a [child of world](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/src/bdd56d02553e51749ea56fb23e81f50a857250d2/sdf/1.5/world.sdf?at=default#cl-16)
or as a [child of model](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/src/bdd56d02553e51749ea56fb23e81f50a857250d2/sdf/1.5/model.sdf?at=default#cl-30). It currently accepts 4 sub-tags: `uri`, `name`, `pose`, and `static` (used for specifying models as static). Ideally, there would be more options there, but that's all we have implemented so far.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2015-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, there's a way, using the `<include>` tag as in [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=attach_gripper&cat=build_robot) tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on 2015-04-11**:
Thanks. I was almost about to say this didn't work, because the [docs](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5) don't mention  and therefore I didn't know how to name multiple inclusions of the same file, which is necessary or else Gazebo throws an error. However, [this question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2764/passing-parameters-to-included-sdf/) mentioned how to use the  tag to solve this problem.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on 2015-04-11**:
Is there documentation for the all the tag that Gazebo uses? http://sdformat.org doesn't seem to cover everything.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-04-12**:
The main documentation is that on http://sdformat.org/spec. We encourage the community to improve the documentation making pull requests to SDFormat's Bitbucket repository, the changes there directly reflect on the website. See for example how [this](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/pull-request/142/update-list-of-supported-joint-types/diff) pull request updated the documentation for joint [types](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=joint#joint_type).